# how to change rowid

Tags: jqgrid

I add new rows with id "new". After I save the row with a new value in the column designated as id (say "code") it remains with id "new" unless I reload the grid or delete the row & add it again with the new id.

Is there another function to change the rowid after the row is saved ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set any attribute inclusive `id`. You should be only very careful with changing of `id` attribute. For example if you use `loadonce: true` option or if you use `datatype: 'local'` there are exist internally `data` and `_index` parameters which cache the current id to row data mapping. So in the case you will be need to update `_index` parameters of jqGrid.

If you will have problems with the implementation you should post the code which you currently use. Some options of jqGrid (like `datatype`, `loadonce`) are very important to know. Additionally is important to know which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#editing) and in which for you use.

Answer (score 1):

To change the id is required a few steps, since jqGrid does not change the primary key of the grid, so we have to manually do all the steps:

```
var new_id = 39; //for example
aftersavefunc: function( old_id ) {

   //get data param
   var row = grid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', old_id);
   console.log(row); //use for firefox test
   row._id_ = new_id;

   grid.jqGrid('setRowData',old_id,{my_id:new_id});
   $("#"+response).attr("id", new_id); //change TR element in DOM

   //very important to change the _index, some functions using the                  
   var _index = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
   var valueTemp = _index[old_id];
   delete _index[old_id];
   _index[new_id] = valueTemp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The is changeRowId function in jqgrid:

```
function aftersavefunc(rowId, response) {

var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
var $tr = $("#" + rowId);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $grid.jqGrid("changeRowid", rowId, json.Id);
        $grid.jqGrid('setSelection', json.Id);
        setFocusToGrid();
    }, 1000);
}
```

setTimeout is required since jqgrid restores old row id after aftersavefunc is called.

Comment: There is no 'changeRowid' function